# What does Faith mean?

Tags: scripture, shraddha

It could mean faith in a particular diety, mantra, ritual, remedy etc. What does faith mean and what does it involve? Does any scripture describe faith?

Comment: Faith mean to believe in something or someone. Like you may believe in Shri krishna to be a God and worshiping him will give you moksha , that is faith.

Answer (score 0):

This is an excellent question. The Sanskrit word sraddha is usually translated as faith in English. This is a problematic translation since faith is mere blind belief while sraddha is more than belief. I have not come across any interpretation of sraddha in scripture. So I am posting excerpts of Swami Tapasyananda's interpretation.

> Sraddha .. is not credulity and superstitious acceptance of unknown
> and unverifiable entities and claims of individuals. It is a positive
> attitude towards the ultimate verities that do not fall within the ken
> of senses and reason, but on which indirect information can be had
> through authentic scriptures and genuine teachers. Sraddha is as much
> a unique quality of the human mind as reason. Animals have no capacity
> for sraddha even as they do not have for reasoning. ..........Sraddha
> also means Bhakti.
>
> ............
>
> Anything that has become a matter of sraddha in a man, unlike what is
> a mere belief, works as an operative force, enthusing him to put the
> content of his sraddha to practice, and to struggle towards the
> realisation of the ideal it presents. Ardour and sincerity are of the
> very stuff of sraddha. .......  Sraddha is a firm and active
> acceptance unlike belief or a conventional conformity which has no
> power to move a person to action.

**Srimad Bhagavad Gita translated by Swami Tapasyananda**